# Kurento Media Server using old OpenCV version

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, kurento

I'm getting this error when I run kurento-media-server-6.0 server. I've added a custom module which is using `OpenCV 3.2`, but it seems like Kurento have issues with the later versions.

Before compiling the module I changed the required OpenCV file in the `CMakeLists.txt` to `set (OPENCV_REQUIRED 3.2.0)`

```
2017-03-03 17:05:20,753540 12549 [0x00007f8512d548c0] warning KurentoModuleManager      ModuleManager.cpp:63 loadMo\
dule()  Module /home/seraf/aa/bb/src/server/libkmsabimpl.so cannot be loaded: /home/sera\
f/aa/bb/src/server/libkmsabimpl.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv7ellipseERKNS_17_InputOutput\
ArrayERKNS_11RotatedRectERKNS_7Scalar_IdEEii
2017-03-03 17:05:20,755425 12549 [0x00007f8512d548c0] warning KurentoModuleManager      ModuleManager.cpp:63 loadMo\
dule()  Module /home/seraf/aa/bb/src/server/libkmsabmodule.so cannot be loaded: /home/se\
raf/aa/bb/src/server/libkmsabmodule.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv
```

Comment: Solution we found is compiling the modules (.so) first, I forgot how we did it in details but maybe this will help